# Express-Validator and req.getValidationResult()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Express-Validator module uses a new function: **req.getValidationResult()** This function returns an object if there are any errors in validation. The object looks like:

```
{param: "field name", msg: "error message", value: "<field input value>"}
```

The question is - how to return a .msg parameter from an object? When I use

```
req.getValidationResult().then(function(result){
        if(!result.isEmpty()) {
            console.log(result.array());
            //return;
        } else {
            console.log('Validation Ok');
        }
```

the function returns an array. But I need only .msg.

Answer (score 3):

The code should be the following

```
req.getValidationResult().then(function (result) {
        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            var errors = result.array().map(function (elem) {
                return elem.msg;
            });
            console.log('There are following validation errors: ' + errors.join('&&'));
            res.render('register', { errors: errors });
        } else {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
req.getValidationResult().then(function(result){
    const {msg} = result;
    if(msg != undefined) {
        console.log(msg);
        //return;
    } else {
        console.log('Validation Ok');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   request.getValidationResult().then(function(result) {
            if (result.array() != '') {
                response.render('route',{validation:result.array()})
                return;
              return;   
            } else {
               //valid
            }
        });
```

view:

```
 <% if(validation) {%>
<ul>
    <% for(var i = 0;i< validation.length;i++){ %>
    <li><%= validation[i].msg %></li>        
    <%}%>
</ul>
<% }%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
req.getValidationResult().then((result) => {
    if(result.isEmpty){
        if(result.array().length > 1){
            return console.log(result.array())
        }else{
            const noticias = {
                titulo: req.body.titulo,
                noticia: req.body.noticia,
                resumo: req.body.resumo,
                autor: req.body.autor,
                data_noticia: req.body.data_noticia
            }
            new noticiasdb(noticias).save().then(() => {
                res.redirect('/noticias')
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(`ERRO AO SALVAR ERRO: ${err}`)
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Perhaps you should comment your code a bit.